# Filter product collection by hidden/external category

Tags: magento2

I am currently using the following code to return the products in category with id `bulbsCategoryId` (I get `bulbsCategoryId` from configuration)

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$this->_catalogLayer->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$bulbsCategory = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($bulbsCategoryId);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($bulbsCategory)
```

This works fine if `bulbsCategory` is part of the store categories hierarchy. However I would like to use a category that is outside the store categories hierarchy (has a different roo category). Suppose I have the following categories:

```
Root (this is the store root category)
  Indoors lights
  Outdoors lights
  Light bulbs
External
  Common light bulbs (I want to filter by this category)
```

All products in `Common light bulbs` are also in `Light bulbs` but not the other way around. In this case the above code returns no results.

Is there a way to achieve this in magento 2?

Or do I have to move `Common light bulbs` under `Root` and hide it?

(I am using magento 2.3.1 - no need for backward compatibility)